# Finding out the name of the original repository you cloned from in Git

Tags: git, version-control, configuration-files

When you do your first clone using the syntax

```
git clone username@server:gitRepo.git
```

Is it possible using your local repository to find the name of that initial clone?

(So in the above example, find `gitRepo.git`.)

Comment: Related post - [How do you get the Git repository's name in some Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15715825/465053)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In the repository root, the `.git/config` file holds all information about remote repositories and branches. In your example, you should look for something like:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = server:gitRepo.git
```

Also, the Git command `git remote -v` shows the remote repository name and URL. The "origin" remote repository usually corresponds to the original repository, from which the local copy was cloned.

Comment: You can also use `git remote show origin` to see much more information about just that remote.

Comment: Looks like these two methods are in the Answer are equivalent - it seems `git remote -v` just reads and writes `.git/config`.

Answer (score 148):

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

Comment: Agreed; this is best because it doesn't require a connection/auth to the git remote server. OP asked "using your local repository" but `git remote show origin` calls out to network.

Comment: This wrapped in a basename as [Casey' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15118089/773623) works well

Answer (score 30):

This is quick Bash command, that you're probably searching for,
will print only a basename of the remote repository:

Where you fetch **from**:

```
basename $(git remote show -n origin | grep Fetch | cut -d: -f2-)
```

Alternatively where you push **to**:

```
basename $(git remote show -n origin | grep Push | cut -d: -f2-)
```

Especially the **`-n`** option makes the command much quicker.

Answer (score 17):

I use this:

```
basename $(git remote get-url origin) .git
```

Which returns something like `gitRepo`. (Remove the `.git` at the end of the command to return something like `gitRepo.git`.)

(Note: It requires Git version 2.7.0 or later)

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this question trying to get the `organization/repo` string from a git host like github or gitlab.

This is working for me:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/^git@.*:\([[:graph:]]*\).git/\1/'
```

It uses `sed` to replace the output of the `git config` command with just the organization and repo name.

Something like `github/scientist` would be matched by the character class `[[:graph:]]` in the regular expression.

The `\1` tells sed to replace everything with just the matched characters.

Comment: typo the end says .get instead of .git    ---- 

`git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/^git@.*:\([[:graph:]]*\).git/\1/'`

Comment: Thanks @MSillence , fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell version of command for git repo name:

```bsh
(git config --get remote.origin.url) -replace '.*/' -replace '.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote show origin -n | ruby -ne 'puts /^\s*Fetch.*(:|\/){1}([^\/]+\/[^\/]+).git/.match($_)[2] rescue nil'
```

It was tested with three different URL styles:

```
echo "Fetch URL: http://user@pass:gitservice.org:20080/owner/repo.git" | ruby -ne 'puts /^\s*Fetch.*(:|\/){1}([^\/]+\/[^\/]+).git/.match($_)[2] rescue nil'
echo "Fetch URL: Fetch URL: git@github.com:home1-oss/oss-build.git" | ruby -ne 'puts /^\s*Fetch.*(:|\/){1}([^\/]+\/[^\/]+).git/.match($_)[2] rescue nil'
echo "Fetch URL: https://github.com/owner/repo.git" | ruby -ne 'puts /^\s*Fetch.*(:|\/){1}([^\/]+\/[^\/]+).git/.match($_)[2] rescue nil'
```

Comment: explain what you did, [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Perhaps add more information, e.g. about the Ruby dependency and on what platform this was tested on (incl. version information).

Answer (score 0):

```bash
git ls-remote --get-url | xargs basename         # gitRepo.git
git ls-remote --get-url | xargs basename -s .git # gitRepo

# zsh
git ls-remote --get-url | read
print $REPLY:t   # gitRepo.git
print $REPLY:t:r # gitRepo
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited for clarity:

This will work to to get the value if the *remote.origin.url* is in the form **protocol://auth_info@git_host:port/project/repo.git**. If you find it doesn't work, adjust the **-f5** option that is part of the first cut command.

For the example **remote.origin.url** of **protocol://auth_info@git_host:port/project/repo.git** the output created by the **cut** command would contain the following:

-f1: protocol:
-f2: (blank)
-f3: auth_info@git_host:port
-f4: project
-f5: repo.git

If you are having problems, look at the output of the `git config --get remote.origin.url` command to see which field contains the original repository. If the **remote.origin.url** does not contain the **.git** string then omit the pipe to the second **cut** command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
repoSlug="$(git config --get remote.origin.url | cut -d/ -f5 | cut -d. -f1)"
echo ${repoSlug}
```

Comment: It is possible that this will result in a blank string if the url for the remote repo is not in the form:

`protocol://git@git_host:7999/project/repo.git`

Adjust the **-f5** down in that case.