# How do you get the Git repository's name in some Git repository?

Tags: git, repository

When you are working in some Git directory, how can you get the Git repository name in some Git repository? Are there any Git commands?

```
# I did check out bar repository and working in somewhere 
# under bar directory at this moment such as below.

$ git clone git://github.com/foo/bar.git
$ cd bar/baz/qux/quux/corge/grault # and I am working in here!
$ git xxx # <- ???
bar
```

Comment: It looks like this is what you're after.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076239/finding-out-the-name-of-the-original-repository-you-cloned-from-in-git

Comment: No, that's probably not what he wants. This might be, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command

Comment: if you use node.js you could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-repo-name

Comment: *There Is No Good Answer* because there is no answer.  Some answers get get you the directory name where you could have elected an alternate name to clone into (or just rename).  Other's have you look at the remote - but multiple remotes is a thing `origin` just happens to be a default.  And one answer suggests look in `.git/description` - sorry if not used consistently by all git hosts this is useless too

Answer (score 268, accepted):

In Git, there's no concept of a repository name. The repository itself is kept under a directory in the file system (the one that contains the `.git` directory) and you can get the name of that directory with the following command:

```bash
basename `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
```

The `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` part gives you the path to that directory and `basename` strips the first part of the path.

---

Another common sense interpretation to a "Git's repository name" is the name used to identify the repository in a Git hosting service (such as GitHub or GitLab). That name can be obtained by looking at the remote information, and a few different ways to achieve that are documented in other answers to this question.

Comment: As @mvp says below, you can change the name of the directory containing the `.git` subdirectory, so it's not true that "if, for the repository name you mean the git root directory name".

Comment: This command gives you exactly that: the name of the directory directly above the .git dir. That is one interpretation for "the name of the repository", and it seems it's the one OP was looking for. Obviously there are other valid interpretations, like the name of the remote origin repository. There's no universal truth in this case and it really depends on what you want.

Comment: Doesn't work in windows 8.1 when my directory looks like "Project 1.1". It only echoes "Project". Plus the folder name here isn't necessarily related to my repo name, right?

Comment: Additional question: how add this to be a string in chain line like :
        git remote add test "admin@`sed -n '1 p' test.ip | basename `basename `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` `:/var/www" ??
As You probably see this line will not work cause of using `` inside ``

Comment: More secure will be to use origin repo name cause basename can be changed on cloning when you will add "." -> "clone repo-name ." 
Bulletproof solution if you want to use repo name in script:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190392/is-there-a-git-command-that-returns-the-current-project-name

Comment: This isn't safe.  Try cd /var/www/html `git --git-dir=<some git repo>/.git rev-parse --show-toplevel` and it'll give you back /var/www/html

Comment: To make sure it works with long directories (with whitespaces), you would have to surround it with double quotes: ```basename "`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`"```

Comment: This command only gives me the local name of the repository directory.

```basename -s .git `git config --get remote.origin.url````, mentioned below, worked as expected

Comment: This command gives the name of the local directory containing the git repository, not the name the the git repository itself. By default `git clone` will use the same value for both of them but it might differ, so I think this is not so safe, event if it works in most of the cases.

Comment: Question was: _When you are working in some Git directory, how can you get the Git repository name?_ This answer gives the name of the Git directory, not the Git repository.

Comment: Powershell : `Split-Path -Leaf (git rev-parse --show-toplevel)`

Comment: For anyone wanting to store this into a variable: `repo_name="$(basename "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)")"`. Check it: `echo "$repo_name"`.

Answer (score 211):

In general, you cannot do this. Git does not care how your git repository is named. For example, you can rename directory containing your repository (one with `.git` subdirectory), and git will not even notice it - everything will continue to work.

However, if you cloned it, you can use command:

```
git remote show origin
```

to display a lot of information about original remote that you cloned your repository from, and it will contain original clone URL.

If, however, you removed link to original remote using `git remote rm origin`, or if you created that repository using `git init`, such information is simply impossible to obtain - it does not exist anywhere.

Comment: You can always get branch name using well, `git branch` :) (active branch will be marked with star `*`).

Answer (score 180):

There's no need to contact the repository to get the name, and the folder name won't necessarily reflect the remote name.

I've found this to be the most accurate and efficient way to get the current repository name:

```
basename -s .git `git config --get remote.origin.url`
```

This should work as of Git 1.8.1.5. Prior to this, the now deprecated `git-repo-config` command would have worked (as early as Git 1.7.5).

Comment: Agreed, this is the most clean answer (I used to have ${PWD##*/} but as you say, the current folder name may be different from the origin)

Comment: yes, i was looking for this, much appreciated.! my folder name differed ;)

Comment: This one also works:


`basename -s .git $(git --git-dir=/<project-path>/.git remote get-url origin)`

Comment: In addition, commad above: `basename -s .git $(git --git-dir=/<project-path>/.git remote get-url origin)` can be launched from anywhere, you do not need to be inside the git repository.

Comment: ```bash
git config --get remote.origin.url
```
Works

Comment: This is the stuff.

Answer (score 52):

In [git v2.7.0+](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt), a subcommand `get-url` was introduced to `git-remote` command.

POSIX shell:

```sh
basename $(git remote get-url origin)
```

PowerShell:

```bsh
Split-Path -Leaf (git remote get-url origin)
```

Comment: I get the `.git` at the end of my string using this method, so I added a split to strip it off: `(git remote get-url origin | Split-Path -leaf).split('.')[0]`

Comment: If you happen to be using this in Jenkins, you'll want to strip off the trailing newline with a `trim()` : `def repo = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: "(git remote get-url origin | Split-Path -leaf).split('.')[0]" ).trim()`

Comment: This is pretty concise and clean! You can use `basename -s .git $(git remote get-url origin)` to remove the `.git` at the end.

Answer (score 31):

If you are trying to get the username or organization name AND the project or repo name on github, I was able to write this command which works for me locally at least.

```sh
▶ git config --get remote.origin.url
# => https://github.com/Vydia/gourami.git

▶ git config --get remote.origin.url | sed 's/.*\/\([^ ]*\/[^.]*\).*/\1/' # Capture last 2 path segments before the dot in .git
# => Vydia/gourami
```

This is the desired result as `Vydia` is the organization name and `gourami` is the package name. Combined they can help form the complete `User/Repo` path

Comment: `git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -r 's/.*(\@|\/\/)(.*)(\:|\/)([^:\/]*)\/([^\/\.]*)\.git/https:\/\/\2\/\4\/\5/'` will convert BOTH `git@dom.tld:User/Repo.git` AND `https://dom.tld/User/Repo.git` to `https://dom.tld/User/Repo`. Got there thanks to your `sed` idea

Answer (score 21):

Other answers still won't work when the name of your directory does not correspond to remote repository name (and it could).
You can get the *real* name of the repository with something like this:

`git remote show origin -n | grep "Fetch URL:" | sed -E "s#^.*/(.*)$#\1#" | sed "s#.git$##"`

Basically, you call `git remote show origin`, take the repository URL from "Fetch URL:" field, and regex it to get the portion with name:
[https://github.com/dragn/**neat-vimrc**.git](https://github.com/dragn/__neat-vimrc__.git)

Comment: Yeah, this is okay, but this will query the remote for an update.  It is better to use `git remote show origin -n` to prevent that.

Comment: Can we update the sed command to also work when the origin url does not end in .git? so 'foo.git' becomes 'foo', but 'foo' is also matched? I guess we need non-greedy matching?

Comment: @ArnoutEngelen I think that the simplest thing to do is to (optionally) strip `.git` with another call to `sed`, I've updated the code in the answer. This way it will work, when the URL does not end with `.git`.

Comment: Makes sense! Good one!

Comment: I went with this method but achieved it using `ack`. Avoids multiple `grep` and `sed` calls, and it works on on my osx with `zsh` where `sed -E` doesn't work as expected. Also puts the requirements in a single regex string instead of spread across a few. Uses named captures groups, `(?<name>...)`, non-greedy matching, `.*?`, and optional matching, `(?:\.git|$)`. Here it is: `git remote show origin -n | ack -m1 --match "\bFetch URL:.*\/(?<repo_name>.*?)(?:\.git|$)" --output "$+{repo_name}"`

Comment: This simpler `sed` worked better on my Mac OSX: `git remote show origin -n | grep h.URL | sed 's/.*://;s/.git$//'`

Comment: There is no such thing as "real name". You may not even have remote called `origin`. Or, you can have multiple remotes, and each can call it differently. In git, repository name (or directory name it is contained) is not explicitly tracked.

Comment: `git --git-dir=<git repo>/.git remote show origin -n | grep "Fetch URL:" | sed -E "s/^.*\/(.*)$/\1/" | sed "s/.git$//"` Worked for me.  @MarkHu was closest

Comment: With MacOS, use single quote: `git remote show origin -n | grep "Fetch URL:" | sed -E 's#^.*/(.*)$#\1#' | sed 's#.git$##'`

Comment: Can you explain me why you need to use single quotes for MacOX?  In which conditions?  And why not for the `grep`, then?  Thanks.

Comment: Git is NOT Github or any other git hosting service. It's totally fine to create and use a git repo without any fetch URL.

Answer (score 8):

A little bit late for this question, but if you:

```
cat /path/to/repo/.git/config
```

You will see the url of the repository which will include the reponame:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/your_git_user_name/your_git_repo_name.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a better way to **unambiguously identify a clone** of a repository.

`git config --get remote.origin.url` and checking to make sure that the origin matches `ssh://your/repo`.

Comment: Actually a stronger condition, requires less parsing.  Might have to specify url name instead of project name, but a small price to pay.  The way everyone else is doing it would break if ".git" occurred in the repo name. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: @ShaneJ you're right and you prompted me to write my own answer which handles the ".git" in the remote origin repo name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58843794/2696867

Answer (score 4):

Repo full name:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url | grep -Po "(?<=git@github\.com:)(.*?)(?=.git)"
```

Comment: In the question, gipcompany mentions being somewhere deep down the directory hierarchy. While I'm not sure what he actually wants (there's an example - *might* be "*get the Git repository name from anywhere in that Git repository*" (which is at odds with how I imagine git repositories)), I see no indication that a/the URL should be known.

Answer (score 3):

you might be after 'origin'

you can use git remote -v

the first word is the repository name which is commonly named as 'origin'

Answer (score 2):

If you want the whole GitHub repository name ('full name') - user/repository, and you want to do it in with Ruby...

```
git remote show origin -n | ruby -ne 'puts /^\s*Fetch.*:(.*).git/.match($_)[1] rescue nil'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems that Git has no such command built in. But you can easily add it yourself with Git aliases and some shell magic.

As pointed out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command), you can use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to show the root of your current Git folder.

If you want to use this regularly, it's probably more convenient to define it as an alias. For this, used `git config alias.root '!echo "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"'`. After this, you can use `git root` to see the root folder of the repository you're currently in.

If you want to use another subcommand name than `root`, simply replace the second part of `alias.root` in the above command with whatever you want.

For details on aliases in Git, see also the [`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: `git config --add alias.root 'rev-parse --show-toplevel'` -- there's no need to throw in the shell for a single-command alias.

Answer (score 1):

This approach using `git-remote` worked well for me for HTTPS remotes:

```
$ git remote -v | grep "(fetch)" | sed 's/.*\/\([^ ]*\)\/.*/\1/'
                                                |  |        | |
                                                |  |        | +---------------+
                                                |  |        | Extract capture |
                                                |  +--------------------+-----+
                                                |Repository name capture|
                                                +-----------------------+
```

Example

Answer (score 1):

You can use: 
    git remote -v

Documentation:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

> Manage the set of repositories ("remotes") whose branches you track.
>   -v
>   --verbose Be a little more verbose and show remote url after name. NOTE: This must be placed between remote and subcommand.

Comment: `git remote -v` is just returning one or more URLs. How is this answering the question?

Comment: As stated earlier, this returns only URLs... and it returns 2 URLs separated by a line break, with unnecessary chars before the URL. SO it creates a problem by including unneeded info, then presents two paths to search, then it still doesn't get the name of the repo.

Comment: i think this is right. the first word is the repository name which is commonly 'origin'

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash function that will print the repository name (if it has been properly set up):

```
__get_reponame ()
{
    local gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)

    if [ $(cat ${gitdir}/description) != "Unnamed repository; edit this file 'description' to name the repository." ]; then
        cat ${gitdir}/description
    else
        echo "Unnamed repository!"
    fi
}
```

Explanation:

```
local gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)
```

This executes `git rev-parse --git-dir`, which prints the full path to the `.git` directory of the currrent repository. It stores the path in `$gitdir`.

```
if [ $(cat ${gitdir}/description) != "..." ]; then
```

This executes `cat ${gitdir}/description`, which prints the contents of the `.git/description` of your current repository. If you've properly named your repository, it will print a name. Otherwise, it will print `Unnamed repository; edit this file 'description' to name the repository.`

```
cat ${gitdir}/description
```

If the repo was properly named, then print the contents.

```
else
```

Otherwise...

```
echo "Unnamed repository!"
```

Tell the user that the repo was unnamed.

---

Something similar is implemented in [this script](https://github.com/aaronryank/prompts/commit/a4b1f28d8a75e529eed0bcd53d2215751393f9da#diff-03fab4f59b7cbc40251559cee88cd0f3).

Answer (score 1):

This one works pretty well with git-2.18.2 and can be launched from outside git target repository:

`basename -s .git $(git --git-dir=/<project-path>/.git remote get-url origin)`

Answer (score 1):

```bash
git ls-remote --get-url | xargs basename -s .git # bar

# zsh
git ls-remote --get-url | read
print $REPLY:t:r # bar
```

Answer (score 1):

If the repo name may have more than 1 folder level then "basename" isn't enough.

I find the following the simplest to cover all cases:

```
git remote get-url origin | sed 's/^.*://;s/.git$//'
```

This command will produce a single line with the repo url wich can easilly be filtered with sed to extract just the name from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine:

```
git remote --verbose | grep origin | grep fetch | cut -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

no better than the others, but I made it a bash function so I can drop in the remote name if it isn't origin.

```
grurl () {
  xx_remote=$1
  [ -z "$xx_remote" ] && xx_remote=origin
  git remote --verbose | grep "$1" | grep fetch | cut -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1
  unset xx_remote
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I just find that there is some repo information inside `.git` directory. So you can just watch `FETCH_HEAD` file in terminal to see repo's name:

**Example:**

```
cd your_project_folder/.git
more FETCH_HEAD
```

**Output:**

```
672e38391557a192ab23a632d160ef37449c56ac        https://bitbucket.org/fonjeekay/some_repo
```

And `https://bitbucket.org/somebituser/some_repo.git` is the name of your repository

Answer (score 0):

You can store the project name in an object in the git object database and reference it in the annotated tag.

For example, the repository name "GnuMake" is the tag name "nameRepo". ssh -F specifies the ssh configuration file khnSrv_al is registered as a remote host

Command: Create and place an object in a git database, get and save a link to the placed object in the annotated tag.

```
git -C /path/dir_git -c user.email=you@example.com -c user.name=ВашеИмя tag -a nameRepo -m 'Имя репозитория' $(echo 'GnuMake'|git -C /path/dir_git hash-object -w --stdin)

al@rznCad:~$ git -C ~/experiments/git -c user.email=you@example.com -c user.name=ВашеИмя tag -a nameRepo -m 'Имя репозитория' $(echo 'GnuMake'|git -C ~/experiments/git hash-object -w --stdin)

al@rznCad:~$ ssh -F /ubData/docs/PktDstSSH/master_config khnSrv_al "git -C /home/al/newRepos/GNU_Make -c user.email=you@example.com -c user.name=ВашеИмя tag -a nameRepo -m 'Имя репозитория' \$(echo 'GnuMake'|git -C /home/al/newRepos/GNU_Make hash-object -w --stdin)"
```

Command: Extract the repository name from a git database object using a tag named "nameRepo"

```
git -C /path/dir_git cat-file blob nameRepo

al@rznCad:~$ git -C ~/experiments/git cat-file blob nameRepo
=>GnuMake

al@rznCad:~$ ssh -F /ubData/docs/PktDstSSH/master_config khnSrv_al "git -C /home/al/newRepos/GNU_Make cat-file blob nameRepo"
=>GnuMake

al@rznCad:~$ ssh -F /ubData/docs/PktDstSSH/master_config khnSrv_al git -C /home/al/newRepos/GNU_Make show nameRepo
tag nameRepo
Tagger: ВашеИмя <you@example.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 25 09:01:18 2023 +0200

Имя репозитория
GnuMake
```

Note that it is not necessary to have anything else in the repository other than this and you can create a repository name at any time