How to get the name of a git repository after fetching it and checking it out?
If I were to clone a repository, git automatically determines the name of the repository and clones it into that directory.
As per the git clone documentation:

<directory>
The name of a new directory to clone into. The "humanish" part of the
source repository is used if no <directory> is explicitly given (repo
for /path/to/repo.git and foo for host.xz:foo/.git). Cloning into an
existing directory is only allowed if the directory is empty.

For example:
git clone https://github.com/root-project/cling
Cloning into 'cling'... 

How do I get the same information after running:
cd foo
git init
git fetch --depth 1 https://github.com/root-project/cling
git checkout FETCH_HEAD

Or, in other words, how do I get the directory foo for host.xz:foo/.git without cloning the repo and taking note of the directory created?

You have to duplicate the logic that git clone would apply. The manual tells you what it is.

foo is specified by you. It could be any other valid name. It's impossible to get foo from a repo URL without taking it down somewhere in the first place.

foo is not specified by me. As per the documentation, foo is The "humanish" part of the source repository is used if no <directory> is explicitly given .

For a known URL, remove the ending /.git or .git and then split the URL by : and /. The last segment is this "humanish" part by convention.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15715825/717372 ?

None of those answers work if I have only fetched the repo, as I do not have any remotes.

@nfl If you do not have any remotes you do not have remote URL. So either you use some URL not currently known to Git. Or you use the name of the working-tree directory.

@phd I just fetched a git repository, surely the URL of that is accessible somewhere? It's in .git/FETCH_HEAD, at the very least.

@nfl If you do not have any remotes you do not have any URL. In shell history, may be.

@nfl it is. That's where you get it. awk '{print $NF;exit}' .git/FETCH_HEAD.

I use basename:
$ basename https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode.git .git
mimedecode

$ basename git@github.com:phdru/ppu.git .git
ppu


And you can get the url with git config remote.origin,url, so basename `git config remote.origin.url` .git

@jthill The OP doesn't have any remotes.

True, and the url can also be got from awk '{print $NF;exit}' .git/FETCH_HEAD.

@jthill What if the base name contains spaces? ;-) My .git/FETCH_HEAD has "8ea716fcecf254300cfd0438f56ac2e5217258f5  branch 'master' of /home/phd/tmp/mime decode"— no escaping/quoting.

I think you and OP can probably figure out quoting.

@jthill I think it can be fixed with a different field separator: awk -F/ '{print $NF;exit}' .git/FETCH_HEAD

That will do it. Plus the quoting on the result as a basename arg.

@jthill I think you can reopen the question and write your own answer.

If you know you're going to be using Bash, you may find this function I wrote for my local CLI useful.†
Essentially, I wanted a command I could pass a git-cloneable thing and have it auto-switch to the directory it clones it into. It sounds like you may be trying to create the same thing.
# Somewhere in ~/.bashrc:

# Clone and switch to a new directory
# Usage:
# gcd https://codeberg.org/h3xx/dotfiles.git     --> cd dotfiles
# gcd https://codeberg.org/h3xx/dotfiles         --> cd dotfiles
# gcd https://codeberg.org/h3xx/dotfiles.git foo --> cd foo
# gcd git@codeberg.org:h3xx/dotfiles.git         --> cd dotfiles
# gcd mybox:dotfiles                             --> cd dotfiles
# gcd /path/to/dotfiles.git                      --> cd dotfiles
# gcd /path/to/dotfiles                          --> cd dotfiles
# gcd /path/to/dotfiles/.git                     --> cd dotfiles
shopt -s extglob # Important!
gcd() {
    git clone "$@" || return
    local TARGETDIR=$_ URL=$1
    if [[ $URL != "$TARGETDIR" && -d $TARGETDIR ]]; then
        cd "$TARGETDIR"
        return
    fi

    # Massage "/path/to/dir/.git/" --> "/path/to/dir"
    # Massage "/path/repo.git" --> "/path/repo"
    # XXX Requires "shopt -s extglob"!
    TARGETDIR=${TARGETDIR%%+(/|.git)}
    # Massage "prefix.dns:repo" --> "repo"
    TARGETDIR=${TARGETDIR#+([0-9A-Za-z.]):}
    # Massage "/path/to/repo" --> "repo"
    TARGETDIR=${TARGETDIR##*/}

    cd "$TARGETDIR"
}

I'm sure there are bugs, but it works for 99% of the git clone operations I do.
I suppose you could use sed or awk for the regexes, but then it would require a separate program. My implementation only uses Bash built-ins, so it'll be faster than spawning a subshell.
†: This piece of code may have had some bugs fixed since writing this question. Check my dotfiles project here for the latest version.

basename $(git config -C "${YOUR_REPO_FOLDER}" remote.origin.url |sed "s/\.git$//")

